# Usar o Execute block no SQL

Tags: sql, firebird

Há alguma forma de buscar dois campos (em tabelas diferentes), compara-los e caso sejam diferentes executar um update? Poderiam me dar um breve exemplo se houver alguma forma, utilizando o `EXECUTE BLOCK`.

Comment: esta resolvido essa questão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo assim:

```
    execute block
as
  begin
    IF ( (select numero from btr01 where numero=150000) = (select numero from btr01 where numero=150001))
        THEN update btr01 set serie='123' where numero=150000;
        ELSE update btr01 set serie='321' where numero=150001;
  end
```